# Strange jagged array assignment behavior

Tags: c#

After I ran the below jagged array assignment (`test[0][0] = 10`):

```
double[][] test = new double[2000][];
Array.Fill<double[]>(test, new double[32]);

test[0][0] = 10;
```

It appears that the first entry (i.e. `[][0]`) of all the 2000 arrays becomes 10.  I was expecting it should update only the first entry of the first array, i.e. `[0][0]`.  Can someone help me understand what my misunderstanding is?

Comment: You stored the *same* 32-item array to all 2000 positions, not a copy of the array. Arrays are reference types and `Fill` stores the value you provided in all array locations. In this case, it's a reference to a single 32-item array

Comment: Oh -  I got your point. The array.fill fills every array with the same array reference. Thanks.  I think I still did it in the same way as vector<vector<>> as in C++.... a bit dangerous!